# Turning off ASP.NET CSS Friendly Adapters

Tags: asp.net, jquery, gridview

The CSS Friendly Control Adapters for ASP.NET are great for creating markup that is easy to style.  A big benefit of the GridView adapter is that it generates THEAD, TBODY, and TFOOT tags, which allow you to do some really great things with libraries like jQuery - for instance, [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) for client-side table sorting.

The problem is that it seems to be a global on/off for the adapters through the CSSFriendlyAdapters.browser file.  What do I do if I already have a slew of GridViews currently in production and only want to use the CSS Friendly Adapters for a new one?

So I would be interested in two types of solutions:

1) A way to extend or modify GridView (a new tag is acceptable) to output THEAD and TBODY tags.

2) A way to conditionally apply or disable CSS Friendly Control Adapters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did something similar to this after doing a little research

you need to subclass the control you want to use (gridview in your case, radiobuttonlist in my case)

```
public class UlRadioButtonList : RadioButtonList
    {
        protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            // Call the base RenderContents method.
            base.Render(writer);
        }
    }
```

Then just have the .browser file refer to your custom subclass, instead of the asp.net control

e.g.

```
<browsers>
  <browser refID="Default">
    <controlAdapters>
      <adapter controlType="FM.Web.Source.WebControls.UlRadioButtonList" adapterType="FM.Web.Source.ControlAdapters.RadioButtonListAdapter" />
    </controlAdapters>
  </browser>
</browsers>
```

Comment: Thank you man, although you didn't help me directly, you saved me a lot of time, giving me a clue of the problem was tackling.. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

CSS Friendly...

> Disabling Adapters
>
> If you explicitly add
>   AdapterEnabled="false" to your
>   server-side tag, these sample adapters
>   will attempt to use the ASP.NET
>   framework's native rendering for the
>   control. Beware: this is not supported
>   and often does not work well.
>   Fundamentally, the framework does not
>   support disabling adapters on a per
>   control basis. The AdapterEnabled
>   attribute is only intended to be used
>   experimentally.

[Source](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/WhitePaper.aspx#Samples)

Alternatively, you can create a class that derives from GridView and overrides the RenderChildren method.  It may take some experimentation to figure out how to make this work.  I haven't looked at how the controls are presented in the GridView to give you any ideas in this regard.  Presumably, you'll just need to figure out which rows are header/foot and render / around them and  around the others.

Comment: Disabling the adapters isn't a very elegant solution, as it would require touching every existing grid.  It would be much better to have a solution where the adapter can be conditionally enabled.

Overriding RenderChildren method seems like too much work, and too error-prone for real use.

Answer (score 0):

I found a method of creating the THEAD and TBODY tags:

Source: [Sortable GridView using jQuery's TableSorter](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/SortableGridViewjQuery.aspx)

Bare Bones Details:

```
myGrid.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
myGrid.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
myGrid.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
```